# Is "in joint work with X, we did ..." or "in joint work with X, I did..."?

Tags: grammatical-number

I don't know which variant is correct:

> 1. (I did this and that... and later on,) in joint work with Mrs. *XY*, we wrote ...
> 2. (I did this and that... and later on,) in joint work with Mrs. *XY*, I wrote ...

Somehow the subject can either be *we* or *I*, even though the action was performed by Mrs. XY and myself.

I want to express no hierarchy, no tone that accidentally implies that we contributed in different amounts. Then I would choose (1). But, on the other hand, (1) could sound redundant, since "joint work" is then superfluous if one uses the plural form, and this makes me think that (2) might be an option.

Is any of the variants correct? Or are both correct but they convey a different intention?

EDIT: A key fact is that only two persons collaborated.

Comment: Personally, I'd avoid "I" and write "@c.p. ABC and @c.p. & XY DEF," where "ABC" is what you did and "DEF" is what you did in collaboration with Mrs. XY. (I find using "&" when listing authors useful to avoid clashes with "and." E.g., X, X & Y, and X, Y & Z, rather than X, X and Y, and X, Y and Z.)

Comment: @user2768 ABCDEF (in your notation) is a work divided in two articles. I was author of the first, Mrs. XY of the second. That's why I tried to put in en a single sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subject of that clause is whoever wrote in joint work with Mrs. XY. Who was in joint work with Mrs. XY?  **I** was.  Mrs. XY was not in joint work with herself.

It is perhaps more obvious if you rearrange it to: "I wrote it in joint work with Mrs. XY."  It would be wrong to write "*We* wrote  it in joint work with Mrs. XY." unless there was a third person involved.